# Json response into selectBox in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, hash

I have the following Json response:

```
[ {
    "Year": 2016,
    "Links": [ {
        "Href": "/v1/Information/YMME/Years/2016/Makes",
        "Rel": "VehicleMakes"
      } ]
  },
  {
    "Year": 2015,
    "Links": [ {
        "Href": "/v1/Information/YMME/Years/2015/Makes",
        "Rel": "VehicleMakes"
      } ]
  },
  {
    "Year": 2014,
    "Links": [ {
        "Href": "/v1/Information/YMME/Years/2014/Makes",
        "Rel": "VehicleMakes"
      } ]
  },
  {
    "Year": 2013,
    "Links": [ {
        "Href": "/v1/Information/YMME/Years/2013/Makes",
        "Rel": "VehicleMakes"
      } ]
  },
  {
    "Year": 2012,
    "Links": [ {
        "Href": "/v1/Information/YMME/Years/2012/Makes",
        "Rel": "VehicleMakes"
      } ]
  } ]
```

As you can see is an Array of nested hashes. I know that there are several post on this but either my skill level or the uniqness of this issue I want to be able to manipulate this data. What method can help me to take this data into a Selectbox so that only the year shows up. So far in my view this is what I have and is only placing the complete object in the select box. I only want to see the year.

```
    <%=select_tag("Year", options_for_select(@caryears))%>
```

Where `@caryears` is the complete Array of hashes or (Objects). By the way I can't use symbols based on the response that is the way I get the data. The idea is to go to the Year link after the person selects the year

Comment: There are lots of tutorials around on how to parse json to html. This isn't a code writing service

Comment: thank you, If you do not want to answer the question I understand. Just don't answer it. Why even bother to reply in a rude way.

Comment: It's not being rude... it's a statement about how this site works. This question doesn't fit the guidelines for a proper question per docs in the help center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the ruby method `collect`.  Collect does an internal iteration for you and returns and array of objects.  You can pass a block to collect, allowing you to define exactly what you want returned.  In you case, it will look something like this:

```
json_object.collect{|o| [o["Year"],o["Links"][0]["Href"]]}
```

Please note the `[0]` after links.  In your example json response, there is only a single array with links defined.  If this changes in the future, or if there are really more than one, this 0 will always return the first link in the list.  Additionally, it will fail if there is no link.

You can read more about collect here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html

The second part of this is `options_for_select`.  This is a nested array, plain and simple, each having 2 params, the first is what is displayed to the user and the second is the value, in this case this url.  You should read up on that one too for complex displays.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Comment: Thankyou @trh this was helpful, I new there was a method but could not find the right one until I saw your post. Thanks